# cs50 pset 2 - readability

Tags: c, cs50

im trying to print the grade level; however, each time i check50 it comes up with this:

':( handles punctuation within a single sentence
expected "Grade 9\n", not "There are more..."'

the only grade level it is properly handling is reading level before grade 1

here is my code:

```
{
    //prompt user for text
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    {
        printf("%s\n", text);
    }

    int count_letters(string letters);
    // count letters
    int letters = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (text[n])
    {
        if (isalpha(text[n]) != '\0')
        {
            letters++;
        }
        n++;
    } //print number of letters
    printf("%i letters\n", letters);
    //count words
    int count_words(string words);
    int words = 0;
    int x = 0;
    while (text[x])
    {
        if ((text[x]) == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
        x++;
    } //print number of words
    printf("%i words\n", words);
    // count sentences
    int count_sentences(string sentences);
    int sentences = 0;
    int s = 0;
    while (text[s])
    {
        if (ispunct(text[s]))
        {
            sentences++;
        }
        s++;
    } //print number of sentences
    printf("%i sentences\n", sentences);


//formula = index = 0.0588 * L(letters per 100 words) - 0.296 * S(sentences per 100 words) - 15.8
    float L = ((float)letters / words) * 100;
    float S = ((float)sentences / words) * 100;

    int grade = round(0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8;

     if (grade < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (grade > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade);
    }
}
```

Comment: You example is incomplete. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you already tried [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+%5Bcs50%5D+pset+2) for this issue?

Comment: You probably want to round the entire result here: `int grade = round(0.0588 * L - (0.296 * S) - 15.8);`

Comment: You also need `>= 16` for the `"Grade 16+"` output. (hint: if there are no conversions involved, `puts ("Grade 16+");` is all you need... You can also compute the number of letters, words and sentences in a single iteration over your input. No need to loop 3-times over the same set of characters. (which is a good thing you are ignoring the suggestion to write the `count_letters()`, `count_words()` and `count_sentences()` function -- which would needlessly loop 3-times over the same input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, of your 3-loops (characters, words, and sentences), both words and sentences are wrong and will not produce the right counts. Why?

For words, you consider every `' '` to indicate a new word. However, if you have leading spaces, or 2 (or more) spaces between sentences, or trailing spaces, your word count will be incorrect.

For sentences, you use the test `if (ispunct(text[s]))` to mark the end of each sentence. This too is incorrect because `ispunct()` will test true for:

> checks for any printable character which is not a space or an
> alphanumeric character.

(see: [man 3 isalpha](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3.html))

That means for every `'` or `';'` or `'"'`, you increment your sentence count ending up with an incorrect answer. This is shown in the very first set of examples in the [CS50 Readability (2023)](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/2/readability/) problem statement, e.g. for `Grade 3` they example is:

> Congratulations! Today is your day. You're off to Great Places! You're
> off and away!

Your code considers `"Today is your day. You"`, `"re off to Great Places"` `"You"` and `"re off and away"` to all be separate sentences.

Instead, as the instructions state, you should only consider `'.'`, `'?'` and `'!'` to mark end-of-sentence. A simple `if` checking all three conditions is all you need, e.g.

```c
  if (text[s] == '.' || text[s] == '?' || text[s] == '!') {
    ...
```

**Use a single-loop and state-variables instead of multiple loops**

As mentioned in the comments, while you can loop over the same text three-times, this is horribly inefficient for longer text. All you need is a single loop and (1) a variable to keep track of whether you are in a word, and another variable to keep track of whether you are in a sentence. A simple `int` will do, set to `1` (or any non-zero value) if you are in a word/sentence and then set to `0` if you are before, between or after a word or sentence.

Say you use `inword` to track if you are in a word reading characters and `insent` to track if you are in a sentence reading words/characters. As you loop *continually* over your text you have only four main conditions to check, e.g.

1. `if (isspace (str[i])) {` to check if you need to increment your word count. Within this condition, you simply check `if (inword) {` to know if you should increment your word count;
2. `else if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '?' || str[i] == '!') {` to check for an end-of-sentence condition, and then you check `if (insent) {` to know if you should increment your sentence count;
3. `else if (!str[i]) {` to check your end-of-string and `break` the loop (equivalent to `if (str[i] == '\0')` and plain old `if (str[i] == 0)`
4. lastly, `else if (isalpha (str[i])) {` to know if you should increment your character count and set your state variables `inword = insent = 1;` (when you read an alpha character, you know you are in both a word and sentence reading characters)

This way, you have a single loop that avoids looping back over the same text multiple times. If you translate that into code and work through the logic, you can end up with something similar to:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* single function to capture chars, words and sentences in a
 * single interation through the string passed as a parameter
 * to the function and compute the chars per 100 words and sentences
 * per 100 words and compute the Coleman-Liau index. Returns the
 * rounded Coleman-Liau index as an integer value.
 */
int coleman_liau_index (const char *str)
{
  int inword = 0,             /* flag in-word (1) or before/between words (0) */
      insent = 0,             /* flag in-sentence (1) or before/between (0) */
      nchars = 0,             /* total number of chars */
      nwords = 0,             /* total number of words */
      nsents = 0;             /* total number of sentences */
  double  l = 0.,             /* avg no. of letters per 100 words */
          s = 0.,             /* avg no. of sentences per 100 words */
          index = 0;          /* Coleman-Liau index */

  for (int i = 0;; i++) {     /* loop continually until out of chars */
    if (isspace (str[i])) {   /* if chars is whitespace */
      if (inword) {           /* if currently inword */
        nwords += 1;          /* increment no. of words */
        inword = 0;           /* set word flag 0 */
      }
    } /* if end-of-sentence character */
    else if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '?' || str[i] == '!') {
      if (insent) {           /* if currently insent */
        nsents += 1;          /* increment no. of sentences */
        insent = 0;           /* set sentence flag 0 */
        /* end of sentence is also end of word, (catches end.Start case)
         * (optional for all given example input -- can you figure out why?)
         */
        nwords += 1;          /* increment no. of words */
        inword = 0;           /* set word flag 0 */
      }
    }
    else if (!str[i]) {       /* if end-of-string (null-char) reached */
      if (inword) {           /* if currently inword */
        nwords += 1;          /* increment no. of words */
      }
      if (insent) {           /* if currently insent */
        nsents += 1;          /* increment no. of sentences */
      }
      break;                  /* break read loop */
    } /* if [a-zA-Z] */
    else if (isalpha (str[i])) {
      nchars += 1;            /* increment total no. of chars */
      inword = insent = 1;    /* set word and sentence flags 1 */
    }
  }

  /* compute l, s and index */
  l = (double) nchars / nwords * 100.;
  s = (double) nsents / nwords * 100.;
  index = 0.0588 * l - 0.296 * s - 15.8;

  if (index > 0) {            /* round index value */
    index += 0.5;
  }
  else {
    index -= 0.5;
  }

#ifdef DEBUG
  printf ("\nnchars : %d\nnwords : %d\nnsents : %d\n"
          "L      : %.2f\nS      : %.2f\nindex  : %d\n\n",
          nchars, nwords, nsents, l, s, (int)index);
#endif

  return index;       /* return index as int */
}

int main (void) {

  char *s = get_string ("Text: ");          /* get string */
  int cl_index = coleman_liau_index (s);    /* compute (int) index */

  if (cl_index < 1) {                       /* classify result */
    puts ("Below Grade 1");
  }
  else if (cl_index >= 16) {
    puts ("Grade 16+");
  }
  else {
    printf ("Grade %d\n", cl_index);
  }
}
```

(the use of `char *s` instead of `string s` is intentional, see [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) (Answer: *No* except for *function* pointers which is fine for a wholly different set of reasons))

Note the `#ifdef DEBUG` that allows you to turn on/off the output of the char, word, sentence counts, the values of `L` and `S` and the `index` value simply by including the `DEBUG` define in your compiler string. For gcc/clang that is `-DDEBUG`, for the microsoft compiler, that's `/DDEBUG`. You can also just put `#define DEBUG` at the top of the code and do it that way.

Also note, you can write the `DEBUG` `printf()` as follows if it makes more sense to you:

```c
  printf ("\n"
          "nchars : %d\n"
          "nwords : %d\n"
          "nsents : %d\n"
          "L      : %.2f\n"
          "S      : %.2f\n"
          "index  : %d\n\n",
          nchars, nwords, nsents, l, s, (int)index);
```

(adjacent string literals are concatenated by the compiler during an early compilation phase before the code is generated. That allows you to make your outputs readable to ensure proper spacing, etc... and the compiler will join them together for you)

**Example Use/Output**

With `DEBUG` defined, the output for the given examples is:

```
$ ./bin/readability
text: Congratulations! Today is your day. You're off to Great Places! You're off and away!

nchars : 65
nwords : 14
nsents : 4
L      : 464.29
S      : 28.57
index  : 3

Grade 3
```

and

```
$ ./bin/readability
text: Harry Potter was a highly unusual boy in many ways. For one thing, he hated the summer holidays more than any other time of year. For another, he really wanted to do his homework, but was forced to do it in secret, in the dead of the night. And he also happened to be a wizard.

nchars : 214
nwords : 56
nsents : 4
L      : 382.14
S      : 7.14
index  : 5

Grade 5
```

and

```
$ ./bin/readability
text: As the average number of letters and words per sentence increases, the Coleman-Liau index gives the text a higher reading level. If you were to take this paragraph, for instance, which has longer words and sentences than either of the prior two examples, the formula would give the text an twelfth-grade reading level.

nchars : 258
nwords : 53
nsents : 2
L      : 486.79
S      : 3.77
index  : 12

Grade 12
```

All of which match the values provided on the CS50 Readability page. (as it does for all of the additional examples given at the end of the problem statement)

Without `DEBUG` defined, the code produces the exact output called for in the problem statement.

Whether you use a single loop, or just fix your three-loop as discussed in the start of the answer, you also need to `round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8)` the entire calculation, not just the first part as you attempted. If you don't want to link with the math library, you can simply do it manually by adding or subtracting `0.5` depending whether the index result is positive or negative, respectively before taking the integer part of the `double` value as your index.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: thank you so much. your explanation was amazing and I see what I was doing wrong. you're a lifesaver :)

Comment: You are very welcome, good luck with your coding!